# How to get Child component data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Here is my data flow from Parent component to Child

**Parent component**

```
    import Add from './AddPage'; //addpage.jsx

    ......

    let data =  
      [
        { id: 0, name: 'orange' },
        { id: 1, name: 'purple' },
        { id: 2, name: 'red' },
        { id: 3, name: 'blue' },
      ];

    .......

    <Add data= { data } />
```

**Child component**

How to get data in child component, i tried following method

```
const Child = ({ data }) => (
  data.map((value => value.name))
);
```

when i use `{Child}`, it's shows

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Chid is not defined

---

**Edit**

Use in my AddForm

```
let AddForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit } = this.props

  return(
    <div className="form-row">
      <div className="col-md-12">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <Field
            name="colors"
            component={renderMultiselect}
            data={Child}
            valueField="id"
            textField="name"
            label="Colors"          
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>{/* form end*/}
      </div>{/* col-md-6f*/}
    </div>/*main row*/
  );
}
```

data using in [Multiselect](http://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/api/Multiselect/#valueField) valueField

Comment: Where do you use `{ Child }`?

Comment: `when i use {Child}, it's shows ` ? i can't see code where you're using `{child}` ?

Comment: @HarryEdward and how you're passing data to Addform ? and you're not taking `Child` from `props` and i can't see anything named `child` in your addform code.

Comment: sorry, i dont get you  :(

Comment: You're doing so many things wrong its hard to figure out what you're attempting to do. In the API you provided, it reads the `data` field should be an array of objects, but you passed in the component `Child`, which usually would be a function or a class, but the error message tells us it's `undefined`. Additionally, you supply `data` as a prop to the `Add` component, but try to access it as a prop of `Child`. Please provide a clear question: a sentence that ends in a question mark (?) or provide expected behaviour (what you're attempting to do) vs actual behaviour of your code.